# Do Enumerable.FirstOrDefault() stop when it finds item?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, ienumerable

I tried searching on MSDN, SO and on Web but could not find answer.

Say I have a collection in which I do `FirstOrDefault()`. Let say it finds the item. Does its stop and returns the item or does it continue searching and hampers performance?

Comment: You might find Jon Skeet's Edulinq posts useful. Here's the one on [First/Single/Last and the ...OrDefault versions](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/11-FirstSingleLast.html) (and the actual answer is yes, it returns as soon as it finds a result. What would be the point of continuing?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: If I had found this link I would not have asked in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are still vague on this, the source code in .NET framework is implemented from [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Core/System/Linq/Enumerable@cs/1407647/Enumerable@cs):

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) {
        if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
    }
    else {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) return e.Current;
        }
    }
    return default(TSource);
}

public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return element;
    }
    return default(TSource);
}
```

Apparently, it will stop if founded

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefault` will iterate until it finds the element, and it only has to iterate the whole `IEnumerable` when it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

It stops and returns.

Here's the relevant decompiled code (for both `FirstOrDefault()` and `FirstOrDefault(predicate)`)

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
  IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
  if (list != null)
  {
    if (list.Count > 0)
      return list[0];
  }
  else
  {
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
      if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        return enumerator.Current;
    }
  }
  return default (TSource);
}
```

Here what it does is check if it implements `IList`, and if it does, return the first item, if there is any. If not, it gets an enumerator and tries to do a `MoveNext`. If it succeeds, it returns `Enumerator.Current`. Else it just returns the default for the type (`TSource`)

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
  if (predicate == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
  foreach (TSource source1 in source)
  {
    if (predicate(source1))
      return source1;
  }
  return default (TSource);
}
```

In here, it first checks all the args are not `null`, and then foreaches until it finds an item that matches the predicate, and then returns it. If there is none, then it just returns the default for that type.

(If you want to know how to get the source, I used [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It's a great tool to have!)

Answer (score 0):

I would hope it does.. but here are a few ways to tell:

1. Test it. Make a big collection (that would take a long time to search), and put the element you want to find at the beginning, then at the end. The time-taken in those two tests should be different, and the first one should be shorter.
2. Look at the [.Net source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx), and see for yourself.